# Excel VBA - Initializing Empty User Types and Detecting Nulls

Tags: vba, excel, initialization, user-defined-types

I have created a user defined type to contain some data that I will use to populate my form. I am utilizing an array of that user defined type, and I resize that array as I pull data from an off-site server.

In order to make my program easier to digest, I have started to split it into subroutines. However, when my program is initialized, I cannot tell when a particular array has been initialized, and so I cannot be certain that I can call a size function to see if the array is empty.

Is there a way to initialize an empty user type or detect a null user type? Currently, I am hard-coding it in and I would prefer a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot check whether user-defined type was initialized before it was sent as an argument to a procedure/function.

I am quoting this example from VBA help

```
Type StateData
    CityCode(1 To 100) As Integer     ' Declare a static array.
    County As String * 30
End Type
```

The County field is initialized to some value, which you can use a base value.
If the user sets this field explicitly, it means it holds some value & remains uninitialized, otherwise.

for e.g.

```
Sub main()
    Dim example As StateData
    MsgBox IsInitialized(example)

    Dim example2 As StateData
    example2.County = "LA"
    MsgBox IsInitialized(example2)
End Sub
Function IsInitialized(arg As StateData) As Boolean
    Dim initCounty As String * 30
    IsInitialized = (arg.County <> initCounty)
End Function
```

Comment: yeah, i havent found a way to check for user-defined type initialization. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to isempty(array) solution -

```
If IsNull(array) then 

   msgbox "array is empty"

End If
```

Comment: hey there. i get the same compiler error for your suggestion as i do for the above with rbobby's solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dim v

if isempty(v) then
    msgbox "is empty"
end if
```

Comment: i think it could be unrelated, but i get a "only user-defined types defined in public object models can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late bound functions" when i try this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
If myObjectVariable is Nothing
```

should work to detect if an object has been initialized.

Edit: "is nothing" DOES work, if it is an *object* variable:

```
Dim blah As Object
If blah Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "blah is nothing!"
End If

Dim foo as variant
If IsEmpty(foo) Then
    MsgBox "foo is empty!"
End If
```

Comment: didnt work! sorry, i forgot to mention that it's a struct/user-type that i created not an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check whether the whole dynamic array of custom types was initialized or not (not just particular element) in VBA, then this might not be possible directly (as none of the IsEmpty etc. functions works on custom types). However you might be able to easily restructure your program to return an array of custom types of size 0 to indicate that nothing was read/initialized.

```
Private Function doStuff() As customType()
    Dim result() As customType

    ' immediately size it to 0 and assing it as result
    ReDim result(0)
    doStuff = vysledek

    ' do real stuff, ... premature "Exit Function" will return an array of size 0
    ' possibly return initialized values
End Function

' then you can all
If (UBound(tabulky) = 0) Then
    MsgBox "Nope, it is not initialized."
End If
```